# How to stop firing tealium tag multiple time on same page

Tags: tealium

I have create Tags 'A' in tealium it's fire on DOM Ready then I call method utag.view({...}) from page and this tag 'A' stared firing again and I want to stop tag firing multiple time on same page. Anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Tag A triggered to fire on DOM Ready, you don't need to call `utag.view({})` yourself. That method is generally only necessary if you're firing from within a single-page application and need to notify that a new pageview has occurred.